# How many numbers end with $0,2,9$?

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

The question is very simple: How many positive integers from $900$ and down end with $0,2$ and $9$?

I think it is either $270$ numbers or $271$ numbers, but I am not sure which one.

Comment: "$900$ and down" is ambiguous. Does that include $0$?

Comment: Yes. Zero is an integer.

Comment: So is $-1$, but you don't want negative numbers, presumably. (And nowhere in your question did you mention integers, although we all assumed that's what you meant.)

Comment: Sorry. I mean positive integers.

Comment: so that doesn't include 0???

Comment: Yes. It includes zero! Do you even know what an positive integer is?

Comment: Well according to wikipedia, an integer is positive if it is greater than zero...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Comment: I am sorry then. You were right! +1

Comment: Hint: instead of looking at the numbers between $1$ and $900$, observe the numbers between $0$ and $899$.

Answer (score 2):

It's 270. Every consecutive set of size 10 starting from 1 (ie, $1\ldots 10, 11\ldots 20$ etc) has 3 numbers ending with 0,2,or 9. There are exactly $900/10 = 90$ such sets in the numbers $1\ldots 900$, so there are $90\cdot 3 = 270$ such integers.

Comment: But is 0 not a positive integer?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Comment: In English, zero is *not* a positive integer. In some languages, such as French, the word that translates as “positive” can mean “positive or zero.” Hence some possible confusion. Zero is “un entier positif” in French. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entier_relatif “L'entier zéro lui-même est donc le seul nombre à la fois positif et négatif.”

Comment: @SteveKass so in French, zero is positive **and** negative? seems messy...

Answer (score 0):

Zero is neither positive nor negative, so you can start with the number $2$ and go up to $900$ since it contains a zero.  Numbers that end in $2$ are $2$ itself, $12$, $22$, $32$, $42$, $52$, and so on to $892$, so that's $90$ of them there.  Also, those numbers that end in $9$ to $899$ are $9$ itself, $19$, $29$, $39$, $49$, $59$, $69$, and so on.  Threre are also $90$ numbers here, but for zero, you start with $10$ and go on to $900$.  We still get $90$ of those numbers, so no matter what digit you use for up to $900$ with positive integers, you get $90$ each, so with $3$ chosen digits, you get $90$ times $3$ is $270$.  **Warning:** Don't use the zero.